# Windows Python - invoking SQL Server stored procedure works only in Python IDLE

Tags: python, sql-server, windows

Windows 10 Pro, Python 3.9, SQL Server 2012.

I have written a bunch of Windows-based Python scripts over the years. One aspect, I use the pypyodbc library to insert data harvested via Python into SQL Server. This has been working well for years whether my Python script is run from the Python IDLE or if the Python script is run from the command line via a Windows batch (.bat) file for automation.

I recently introduced calling a, fully operational, SQL Server stored procedure from my Windows-based Python script that is already doing SQL Server inserts successfully. When I run my Python script from the Python IDLE, the SQL Server inserts and the stored procedure runs successfully.

PROBLEM: when I run my Python script via a Windows batch (`.bat`) file, the SQL Server inserts are successful but the stored procedure does not run. I have also tried "Run as administrator" for the .bat file invoking my Python script. Still, the stored procedure will not run.

Given the SQL Server inserts are successful no matter what and the stored procedure WILL ONLY run when originating the Python script via the Python IDLE, perhaps this problem is a Windows configuration issue?

Thanks in advance for any guidance.

Comment: It might sound stupid, but I would check two things, first is that I saved the Python file after making the change, the 2nd thing is to make sure that the py file that I am trying to run is the correct file with the code I want to run , I did it a lot of times and never saw a situation where it matter the way we call the Python code

Comment: Nir thank you. The Python-invoked MS SQL Server Insert statements are successful under any/all scenarios described above. It is only the MS SQL Server Stored Procedure that will not run and only when running the Python script from the command line. Therefore, the python file and the python code are correct.

Comment: Did you check the DB user you are using has permission to run store procedure ?

Comment: Nir - thanks I will look into SQL Server permissions.

Comment: marc_s - I updated my post to more accurately reflect the SQL Server version which is 2012. Apologies.

Comment: Nir - I ran this command on for the account Python uses to login to SQL Server "GRANT EXECUTE TO [user]" It didn't fix the problem.

Answer (score 0):

I located the problem. It was a permissions problem in SQL Server. This is now closed. Thanks.